# odd formatting in netbeans 7.4

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7.4

"odd formatting"

[image]

```
 public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        // get current time and date
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        // display greeting
        if (hour < 12) {
            System.out.println("Good morning.
```

Heres the jist of my problem, tried out eclipse for awhile didn't really like it and switched back to eclipse. Now that 7.4 is the newest release, i downloaded it thinking it would be better. however when you look at the attached image of my code, all the spacing is messed up. I want the code to look normal( like the code above). i know that this doesn't really make a difference, but it makes it a pain in the ass to read. Is there a way to have 7.4 follow the formatting rules of some previous versions of NetBeans

Comment: Probably a problem with the font, not with NetBeans. Did you try to use a different font for the editor?

Comment: Its an issue with your computer's font set. I had this issue once before on a Chinese version of Windows XP (and unfortunately didn't find a solution for). Within the settings for netbeans, it believes its using a monospaced font when its actually using some other font (Possibly because the monospaced font isn't available)

Comment: If you add a line which imports "java.util.Calendar", does it stop italicizing the Class?  It looks like NetBeans is trying to tell you it doesn't recognize the Class because it hasn't been imported...